# Can Microsoft cognitive services be used in Firebase?

Tags: android, azure, firebase

Is there any way to import the Microsoft cognitive services from Azure to Google Firebase? As to we can use the cognitive services in Firebase instead of Azure.

Comment: What do you mean by "import in Firebase"?

Comment: I mean to ask that even if you don't have an Azure account can you get cognitive services to use on firebase

Comment: No.  Have you tried creating a free account?  https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/sign-up

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some details in order to answer your question:

- [Cognitive services](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/documentation) are a set of APIs, SDKs and services available to developers.
- Cognitive services is not an on premise solution that can be installed in different Cloud Providers.
- [Cognitive services pricing and billing](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/pricing) is managed through an Azure subscription.

This said, cognitive services is not meant to be moved between cloud providers.